# Assets folder in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to use a JSON files in my project.

But Ember opens an error page. I mean a 404 page. In `router` - `this.route('error')`

```
$.getJSON('/myfolder/file.json').then(function (data) { 
});
```

I store a files in `/public/assets/myfolder`.

I get an error page when I call `/assets/myfolder` or `/myfolder`. But my folder is in `dist` and `public` folders

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the error page to the question?

Comment: Also would be useful to see exact call you perform

Comment: @NTDLS, I edited my question

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, I fixed my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add /assets folder at start your url. But if you want mock some data. Please add a mock server. It's easy load data from there and it up with your app.

```
ember g http-mock model
```

> A basic ExpressJS server will be scaffolded for your endpoint under /your-app/server/mocks/posts.js. Once you add the appropriate JSON response, you’re ready to go. The next time you run ember server, your new mock server will be listening for any API requests from your Ember app.

https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#mocks-and-fixtures

https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#raw-assets